# Normal scrolling in Win 10 Pro installed on Macbook Pro

Tags: bootcamp, windows, trackpad, macos

I installed a Win 10 Pro on my Macbook Pro. I also installed TRackpad++ and the whole is great! The only strange thing is scrolling. Scrolling is not fluid and stops at end of every page. I cannot do that when you swipe a bigger one and the content is scrolls for longer time and decent amount of content goes away.

I haven't found a solution for getting back this scrolling. Is there any solution for this?